# How to implement javascript validation?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to get this code to work, but it's not working. I want to validate something with JavaScript

Code:

```
function validate() {
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]_$/;
    u = document.getElementById("username").value;
    if (validate.value.match(letters) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("username is requiried");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It seems you are new to javascript. so what you want to do?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show the rest of the HTML document please. Also, this may be useful: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add also your html code in your question.

Comment: Please narrow down the issue and explain what is *not working*.

Comment: `if (validate.value.match(letters) { ...` should *probably* be `if(u.match(letters)) { ...` you've got a missing parenthesis and you're assigning `value.match` to a variable that hasn't been declared.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not proper and also have lots of mistakes. I have corrected and implemented validations. Try the below code.

```
<script>

    function validate() {        
        var u = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var p = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z]_$/;    
        if(u == '') {
            alert("username is required");
            return false;
        }
        if(!u.match(letters)) {
            alert("username should be letters");
            return false;
        }
        if(p == '') {
            alert("password is required");
            return false;
        }        
        if(p.length < 6) {
            alert("password length is too short");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Hope this will help